# Bind width of one element to width of sibling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to set the max width of a `<p>` tag to the width of a sibling `<p>` tag.

Here's the relevant code:

```
<div>
  <p>
    <h2 id="annotation_preview_title"> <%= t('marker.annotation.preview_title') %></h2>
  </p>
  <p id="annotation_preview" style="word-wrap: break-word;"></p>
</div>
```

I'm using jquery to populate the content of `annotation_preview` and I would like it's width to not exceed the width of the `<p>` tag surrounding `annotation_preview_title`.

Here's an image of the problem I'm trying to solve:
[image: Annotation is too long]

I'd like to get the `annotation_preview` to wrap once it reaches the width of `annotation_preview_title`. I've tried using css as found [here (from another SO post I closed)](https://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/H3Ngz/) and tried playing with jQuery doing something to the effect of:

```
var previewParagraph = document.getElementById("annotation_preview");
var title = document.getElementById("annotation_preview_title");
previewParagraph.maxWidth = title.width;
```

Neither of which worked. I'm open to any and all solutions (pure JS, pure CSS, mix, whatever).

Comment: <h2> doesn't belong inside of a <p>. Anyway, is the title in display:inline? If not then though the content is short, its width is still 100%

Comment: I would just put a `max-width` on the parent div that contains them both.. or a fixed width. It's the easiest way to get something similar to what you're looking for.

Comment: Yeah, putting a ```max-width``` on the div would be easiest but I'd like to avoid that because I'm localizing the ```annotation_preview_title```.

@Neps I know ```<h2>``` doesn't belong in ```<p>``` but that's used elsewhere in the code and I'm just trying to keep it consistent. I'm not quite sure what you mean by "though the content is short, its width is still 100%". There's currently no styling on the title.

Comment: Width of the element itself as opposed to the length of text inside it. Inspect or add a temporary border to annotation_preview_title and you'll see it.

Comment: Like this? http://imgur.com/hQ9CauU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're already using jQuery:

```
$("#annotation_preview").css("max-width", $("#annotation_preview_title").width());
```

I haven't tested it, but something along these lines should do the trick.

Comment: that resulted in in the following error: ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'css' of null```. I tried doing ```previewParagraph.css("max-width", title.width());``` but that resulted in the following error: ```Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function```

Comment: Turns out ```title.width()``` was the problem with my variation. However, ```var width = title.width;``` results in ```width``` being ```undefined```.

Comment: the .css() method won't work without the jQuery selector. Your first error means `$("#annotation_preview")` isn't matching anything. Make sure this script is running after all the relevant elements have loaded.

Comment: The script runs after every key-up in the text box under the ```Create New Annotation``` header shown in the image in the original post. Is it possible that ```$('#annotation_preview")``` doesn't find the element but ```document.getElementById("annotation_preview");``` does?

Comment: You have a single quote and a double quote in your $() selector. Is it that way in your code too?

Comment: Also, you don't need to set that css on every key-up. Just once should do, after the elements are loaded.

Comment: No, that was just a typing mistake on SO. I was planning on refactoring it out once I had some working code.

Comment: Turns out someone on the project had reassigned ```$```. I had to use ```jQuery``` instead. ie: ```jQuery("#annotation_preview").css("max-width", jQuery("#annotation_preview_title").width());```

Comment: Ah! I didn't think about that. Glad you figured it out!